# Why "make" is more correct than "cause" on that sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences, synonyms

I just did the Cambridge general English test and I can't say why one of my answers was wrong:

The sentence was:

> The middle paragraph has to be very convincing and ...... an impact on the reader.

I answered "cause" and the right answer was "make", why is that?

Comment: "Cause" is often associated with a negative effect, whereas in this case the effect should be positive.

Comment: [These Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cause+an+impact%2Cmake+an+impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccause%20an%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20an%20impact%3B%2Cc0) suggest you should have got a hundredth of a mark. 'Cause an impact' sounds very unnatural here (not many practised Anglophones would consider using it), and while one could argue it's not ungrammatical, idiomaticity is at least as important.

Comment: I would say that the sentence could be written as "The middle paragraph has to be very convincing and _create_ an impact on the reader." This demonstrates why 'make' is the better chioce. 'Make' can mean 'compel', 'create' or 'fabricate' while 'cause' can only mean 'compel' or 'initiate'. Since the impact is 'created' then 'make' is the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The middle paragraph has to be very convincing and ...... an impact on the reader.

The answer is that “cause” is not wrong, but “make” is better – it is more idiomatic.

The example can be reduced to “The paragraph has to ...... an impact on the reader.

There is overlap in the meanings of *cause* and *make* but it is impossible to overstate the importance of context. In this context, *impact = a strong impression*. “To make an impact” is the set collocation/verbal clause *in this context*. It implies that the reader will receive the impact which the paragraph **already** possesses.

In “The paragraph has **to cause** an impact on the reader”, the nuance is that the paragraph does not possess “an impact.” It creates an independent “impact” and there is a vague feeling that “impact” is being used literally: there will be an impact somewhere near, or upon the person of, the reader.

“Cause” would work in “The paragraph has to cause an impact on the **reader’s emotions**”